# Media Query doesn't reponds

Tags: html, sass

So the situation is a little bit weird because there are alot of questions already been asked on media queries but unfornulately I couldn't find my way in most of them. Actually I am working on a simple website and I wrote a media which looks like this.And notice that sass also notifies me that  no grid-area have been specified for the grid-template-areas present in the media whereas I specified it out of the media on top.And just for a precision my media is at the bottom of my code.

```
@media (max-width: 769px) {
    .top-container {
        grid-template-areas:
            "showcase showcase"
            "top-box-a top-box-b";
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work,even with the meta Tag and the viewport specified.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Thanks...

Comment: You can try with easy CSS property like "height:, width:" if work then problem in your  "grid-template-areas:". We found your @media query is fine.

Comment: just to test, try to add !important after each property. and inspect the element in Inspector to see if any other CSS are overwriting the properties from the media query

Comment: thank Stein The Ruler actually this was overwritten by a more specific selector